# What does "rummun" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"They have had a bitter quarrel I think" said he and bit into the bagel. "They're rummuns" said he chewing it.

Comment: The word "rummun," as WS2 observes in his answer, is found occasionally in the writings of the famous veterinarian/author James Herriot, who spent decades tending to animals belonging to the residents of the Yorkshire Dales in northern England (specifically Darrowby or Thirsk). If a client said to the vet, "It's a rummun, Mr. Herriot, he or she meant, "It's a strange case, Mr. Herriot." In other words, it's something odd and hard to explain; it might even leave you stumped. Don

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This could easily be Norfolk dialect, though the word *rummun* has clearly been part of general British speech. It is nowadays a bit dated.

It means 'rum one', the adjective *rum* meaning *strange, odd, different, peculiar etc*.

A Norfolk expression *Tha's a rummun ent it* means 'It's a strange thing, isn't it'.

*They're rummuns' would mean simply 'they are odd/strange ones'. It can equally be applied to people as to objects etc.

*Rum* used as an adjective in this way is confirmed by the OED (sense 6) as dated, and they are uncertain of its etymology. It is predominantly British, but I wouldn't mind betting that many older-generation Australians, New Zealanders etc use it. A few of the more recent examples from the OED:

1955   J. Thomas No Banners vii. 61   ‘This is a rum go,’ Alfred said.

1977   J. I. M. Stewart Madonna of Astrolabe xi. 153   Some Scottish names are distinctly rum. Yours is.

1993   A. Habens in M. Bradbury & A. Motion New Writing 2 247   It's a rum do if a chap isn't allowed to remember what he remembers.

The adjective *rum* gives rise to may composites e.g. *rum-looking, rum-sounding etc*

Comment: I've more often seen the spelling *rum 'un* with a space and apostrophe.

Comment: @NateEldredge In this register one spells as one pleases!

Answer (score 0):

Popular Tasmanian slang; an eccentric or odd person; a character; a scally-wag.  Still in use to this day in Southern Tasmania.

Comment: How do you know? Can you cite any references?